# How to Implement autocomplete for a textbox using local json file jquery or angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, autocomplete

Here i want to develop bus ticket booking website i want to display cities when the user types. I have tried many articles they are all calling remote api to get the data. But i don't know how to get the data from local json. i have done it autocomplete extender for data from server in asp.net. Now i want to do it in jquery for local json file

here is my json file :

```
{"stationList":[{"stationName":"10 dol","stationId":-1},{"stationName":"Adduroad","stationId":4508},{"stationName":"Adilabad","stationId":4198},{"stationName":"Adoni","stationId":2893},{"stationName":"Afzulgunj","stationId":-1},{"stationName":"Agaratala","stationId":-1},{"stationName":"Agartala","stationId":-1},{"stationName":"Agra","stationId":2486},{"stationName":"Ahmedabad","stationId":2434},
"apiStatus":{"success":true,"message":"SUCCESS"}}
```

i don't know how to implement in jquery or angularjs i have tried many articles found on the internet 
[jQuery autocomplete using a local json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430448/jquery-autocomplete-using-a-local-json-file)
[autocomplete textbox and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996672/autocomplete-textbox-and-angularjs)

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Answer (score 1):

I would use angular ui-select. It offers very flexible search and display. You can use local data or retrieve the data from $http get:

http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

```
  <h3>Array of objects with single property binding</h3>
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.selectedPeopleSimple" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.email as person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.selectedPeopleSimple}}</p>
```